# Can you copy files onto the Xbox 360 HDD?

Tags: xbox-360, windows-7

How can you transfer files from a PC onto the Xbox 360 HDD?

If you connected an Xbox formatted Hard disk/Flash drive into a PC, is it possible to add to the games installed? and is there a driver/software that can view/edit files on such drives? Is the filesystem viewable and editable in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

A normally formatted memory stick (not one for save files) can be used to play music/videos etc. stored on it. You can't copy files to the Xbox, but you can use them from it.

You can't add to the Xbox formatted filesystem from a computer.